# Prove that this is a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

> I'm supposed to show that If X is the set of all functions on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\displaystyle d(f,g)= \int^{b}_{a}|f(x)-g(x)|dx\,$, then $(X, d)$ is a metric space.

But I don't think it is. The problem I'm having is that in order for $(X,d)$ to be a metric space, it must be true that $d(f,g) = 0$ iff $f=g$. But d could also be $0$ if, for instance,

$f(x) - g(x)$ is odd and is symmetrical across $x=(a+b)/2$

Am I right about this or am I missing something?

Sorry, about the format by the way. I don't know how to type the actual symbols on here!

Comment: this is a metric space! integrand is positive so integral will be zero only if integrand is zero

Comment: Just a small note: not every function on $[a,b]$ is (Lebesgue) integrable. So $(X,d)$ as defined cannot be a metric space, since the "metric" cannot be applied to every element in $X$. The answer given below certainly clarifies how to prove that the set of integrable functions on $[a,b]$ is a metric space, with the above metric.

Comment: @Stromael's note is not small.  The problem is unclear.  If it is "the set of all functions" then $d$ does not make sense.  If restricting to Lebesgue integrable functions, then it is still not a metric but not for the reason indicated.  You can have $f$ such that $\int|f| = 0$ but $f$ is not everywhere $0$.  If restricting to continuous functions, or instead working with equivalence classes of integrable functions, it can define a metric.

Comment: There is a sense in which this is trivial. Obviously you must consider equivalence classes of functions (because of the measure 0 effect) or restrict the functions in some way to ensure you get at most one member of each equiv class. But then the result is almost trivial.

Comment: Of course one must take equivalence classes. Please forgive an analyst's hidden assumptions. :-)

Comment: oops! yeah, it was supposed to say "The set of all integrable functions..."

Answer (score 1):

No: you are taking the integral of the absolute value of the difference  $$\displaystyle d(f,g)= \int_a^b \left|f(x)−g(x)\right|dx$$ while your counterexample would apply if you were taking the absolute value of the integral of the difference $$\displaystyle \left|\int_a^b (f(x)−g(x))\,dx\right|.$$

You may need to watch out for the possibility that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ on a set of measure zero, but apart from that you will have $\left|f(x)−g(x)\right|$ as non-negative by definition, and positive if they differ, making the integral positive if they differ on a large enough subset of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Oh! Ok thanks for pointing that out. Duh.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing that the limits of integration is arbitrary. The $a$ and $b$ are to be any number, you don't determine them, they are given to you.

Comment: That isn't relevant.  The same properties will apply regardless of the interval.

Comment: That's what I mean. It is regardless of the interval.

Comment: I do not see how the point of possible confusion mentioned here is relevant to the question.  There is no assumption that $a$ or $b$ have any particular value in the question.  "you are confusing"--who is confusing this, where?

Comment: @JonasMeyer, he said it might not work if $x = (a+b)/2$, but he doesn't choose the limits of integration.

Comment: OP refers to the midpoint of the segment, which exists regardless of what the segment is.  OP does not make any assumptions about what $a$ or $b$ is.  The point of confusion illustrated there was that even if $f$ is odd about that midpoint, it does not mean that $|f|$ is.

Comment: Oh okay, I misunderstood.